# Como visualizar el Thumbnail de mi pagina web al compartirla ?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

[image: Thumbnail web - share social]

Hola quisiera que me ayudaran a encontrar la forma de ubicar una imagen Thumbnail, al momento de compartir el enlace no se visualiza www.miartesano.com, pero en la pagina ejemplo www.bancolombia.com si se muestra una imagen.

existe algún plugin de Wordpress o algún código CSS o HTML para logra esto?

les agradecería mucho el que me ayuden

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez puedes probar esto con tus enlaces:
https://pablomonteserin.com/imagen-destacada-wordpress-facebook/
Por si se perdiera el enlace:
Digamos que para publicar un enlace con imagen destacada facebook tiene un procedimiento que posiblemente puedas googlear.
Yo no conozco bien el procedimiento. Por eso te he buscado el enlace para ayudar.

Es un error de configuración, pienso.

Comment: Hola DrManhattan. Gracias por responder pero las respuestas que son solo un enlace se consdieran de baja calidad. Has de explicar el contenido de dicho enlace aplicado al problema del OP. Si ese enlace se rompiera y no explicases nada, la respuesta perderia sentido. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si en tu página de inicio tienes puesta una imagen destacada, normalmente el código output para las RRSS tiene en cuenta la imagen destacada de la página o post.
Una vez puesta la imagen destacada yo te recomendaría que fueras al debug de URL de facebook ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ) donde introduciendo tu URL podrás obtener todos los datos que facebook ve para así comprobar si la imagen se ve.

En el caso de que te surja dicho problema con los artículos/posts te recomendaría que instalaras, si aún no lo tienes, el plugin Yoast SEO ( https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ ) ya que en ese mismo además de tocar para SEO nos deja la opción de RRSS donde podremos poner una descripción e imagen tanto para facebook como para twitter.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!